# Caching options for Azure App Configuration with JS sdk

Tags: javascript, azure, caching, azure-app-configuration, feature-flags

Any ideas for caching or otherwise reducing the number of requests when using Azure App Config for feature flagging?

The .NET sdk docs does provide [some options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/howto-best-practices#reduce-requests-made-to-app-configuration) including a [.SetCacheExpiration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.azureappconfiguration.azureappconfigurationrefreshoptions.setcacheexpiration?view=azure-dotnet) method for setting a cache expiration time, but there doesn't appear to be anything similar in the js sdk.

Any pointers will be much appreciated - thanks!

Context: using [Azure App Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/) for feature flagging in a Next.js application using the [JS sdk](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/tree/main/sdk/appconfiguration/app-configuration).

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't any feature management support for JS like .NET in App Configuration today.